# create a save Attributes then call GetCustomAttributes doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    [Save]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Name = "qwe asd zxc";
        LoadProperties(this);
    }    

    public void LoadProperties(object viewModel)
    {
         var properties = viewModel.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Save),false);
    }
}

public class Save : Attribute{}
```

the properties variable in the load properties method has 0 item
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
var properties = viewModel.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Save),false).Any())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: And the reason _why_ the original code does not work, is because the attributes of the `MainViewModel` _class_ are being inspected, instead of the attributes of its properties.